# Speed of an explosion

Tags: material-science, explosions, shock-waves

If I am standing $10$ feet away from an explosion, what would hit me first? Shock wave, sound, shrapnel, etc  (besides light!)

If the shock wave was powerful enough, is it possible to be thrown out of the blast radius and not get hit by shrapnel.

If my question(s) are missing something technically, please help develop the question instead of ripping the question and not answering it.